# MongoDB search by nested dynamic sub field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Trying to find a way to reach to sub sub field which dynamic sub field in between. Not sure how to reach there. Looking for something like $ used for arrays.

My data structure looks like

```
  {
    _id: ObjectId("59355deee13f1a1260f17421"),
    product: {    
      shirt: {
        color: "black"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("59355deee13f1a1260f17422"),
    product: {    
      top: {
        color: "red"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("59355deee13f1a1260f17423"),
    product: {    
      shoes: {
        color: "black"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("59355deee13f1a1260f17424"),
    product: {    
      belt: {
        color: "brown7"
      }
    }
  },
```

Looking for equivalent of

```
db.things.find({product.$.color: "black"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
db.getCollection('things').find({$where: function() { 
for (var field in this.product) { 
    if (this.product[field].color == "black") return true;
}
return false;
```

}})

Comment: Now I am looking to fit this in Mangoose

Comment: glad it helped..!!. Could you able to fit this in Mongoose ??

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned document can be represented as an embedded document since all data belongs to common entity and facilitates conveniency in querying data from an embedded document using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator.Its representation should be as follows.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59355deee13f1a1260f17421"),
    "product": [{
            "name": "shirt",
            "color": "black"
        },
        {
            "name": "top",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "name": "shoes",
            "color": "black"
        },
        {
            "name": "belt",
            "color": "brown7"
        }
    ]
}
```

According to description as mentioned in above question to fetch documents in which value of color field is black please try executing following query in MongoDB shell.

```
db.things.find({product:{$elemMatch:{color:'black'}}})
```